# update monaco-editor configurations in standalone browser editor

Tags: configuration, tokenize, monaco-editor

I'm using the `monaco.editor.colorize` and `monaco.editor.tokenize` API in my app for colorizing and formatting a long line of logs (I defined the language id), however I find no way of configuring, for example, `editor.maxTokenizationLineLength`, to prevent it from giving up when the line length exceeds the default 20000.

I went through the monaco source code and found the following hack. Is there any way to do this properly, or do I need to raise a feature request?

```
// @ts-ignore
import { IConfigurationService } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/platform/configuration/common/configuration";
// @ts-ignore
import { StandaloneServices } from "monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/standalone/browser/standaloneServices";

(()=>{
  // patch 
  StandaloneServices.get(IConfigurationService).updateValue(
    "editor.maxTokenizationLineLength", 40000
  );
})();
```

I found that when monaco performs `setMonarchTokensProvider`, it creates a `MonarchTokenizer` instance with a config source singleton `StandaloneServices.get(IConfigurationService)`, and I found no public apis for mutating it properly (instead of the hack above).